# Display Badges in my profiler

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges, flair

[image]
I think this picture is self description my badges is wrong.Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is mentioned in the flairs tab.

> Flair is only updated once every 24-36 hours.

Check your [flair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10940813/shahrooz-jefri/flair) page again. It must've updated by now.

---

In fact, it has:

[image: Flair]
<sub>(source: [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/1968030.png))</sub>